# Voltage demultiplexer circuit

Tags: voltage, switches, amplifier

Suppose we have output signal from a another circuit in range from 0-7.5V. However, this signal is polynomial coded:

- function A: +0.5V
- function B: +1V
- function C: +2V
- function D: +4V

... so output voltage of 5V means function B and D were triggered, voltage of 3.5 V means functions A, B and C were triggered ... etc.

Is there an IC that can handle de-multiplexing of this signal and have like 4 outputs which are set to 5V (or similar) when specific functions are detected?

Comment: look at ADC (analog to digital) converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looking for a ADC called flash converter. You can realize this with stacked comparators. Take a look at : [4 Bit Digitizer](http://www.paia.com/ProdArticles/ek7.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Analogue comparators can compare an unknown voltage against a threshold (say 0.75V) and give a logic output to say whether the unknown voltage is above or below 0.75V. This will differentiate between A and B (or other more complex functions).

But realistically it's just as easy to use a small MCU with an ADC input. It reads the analogue voltage and outputs 4 lines corresponding to the presence (or not) of the four functions A, B, C and D.

If you still want to use comparators then you'll need 16 of them set at multiples of 0.5V starting at 0.75V then 1.25V then 1.75V etc.. After this you'll need a bunch of steering logic gates to decode the sixteen outputs. Go for an MCU is my recommendation